# Take 20 random rows from one table and insert them into another table (single row) as columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Hi I am using SQL Server 2012 and I have a table with 1000 questions in it as rows. I need to randomly select 20 of those questions and then insert them into a single row on another table as separate columns.

I want to do something like this.

```
select top 20 questionid from questions order by newid()
insert into questionsets values (q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6....)
```

I have tried doing this various ways but am having trouble getting my head around in in a not to expensive way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try inserting after PIVOTing your result set:

```
INSERT INTO 
    questionsets    (
    Q1,
    Q2,
    .
    .
    Q20)
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY questionid) RNum FROM(
        SELECT TOP 20 questionid FROM questions ORDER BY NEWID()
)x)y PIVOT (MAX(questionid) FOR RNum IN ([1], [2], [3], ..., [20]))as pvt
```

Comment: Hi thanks after doing some research it looks like pivot tables are exactly what I am looking for. However that is going over my head slightly. Is there anyway you could break this down for me?

Comment: I didn't get you... break down means?

Comment: It means to explain how it works, sorry I have looked online and am having trouble getting my head around how pivot table syntax works.

Comment: Please check these two links (since I am not good in explaining :)) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx, http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/